# After adding videos to playlist, what is the easiest way to consume them?

Tags: video

Is it a playlist page or a widget on every page(like youtube)?

If widget, is the best location at the bottom or top of the page or something else?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the two options you mention are basically the same. The important thing is to not require the user to navigate back and forth between the list and the player. Hence, the playlist should contain the player in some kind of master-detail relationship. And then it's just a matter of perspective and design, you can make it look like a playlist widget on a player page, or like a player area on the playlist page.

As to location - the top of the page probably contains the header and some navigation, and maybe additional features, so I wouldn't add more stuff there. If the left-hand side is unoccupied, then I think I'd put it there. A vertical list on the left is more scannable, it scales better, and it's easier to work with than a horizontal list at the bottom. If it's unavailable, then the bottom. Wouldn't put it on the right though.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is, as in many cases, "it depends".  For example, if you are going to allow comments on the videos, or if you have a lot of related information that you would like to present, then a widget-per-page makes the most sense.

If widget, I'd place the video on top.